# If it is not going to actively heated or cooled, is there any value in insulating a garage?

Tags: insulation, garage

In Southern California, during new construction with a finished garage, the cost of adding insulation at this point should be low.

But if the space will not have any active cooling or heating elements (outside of a tankless water heater and, perhaps, a cat), is there any value in insulating it?

Everyone loves going from a cool house in to a hot garage or vice a versa. Would insulating it make any difference? Would it not get as hot in the summer or as cold in the winter?

Seems to me that it would retain whatever temperature it have longer (whether hot or cold) with the insulation than without, and one could "reset" the temperature of the garage by opening the door for a few minutes to the outside (for example, open it in the cool morning in the summer hoping to better maintain that during the day). Just not sure if it would be enough to notice or bother with.

Historically the garage has mostly been closed vs opened several times a day for cars. Whether that will be the case at the new house is up for debate.

Comment: Is it an attached garage it a separate building?

Comment: It's an attached garage.

Comment: Don't forget that insulation helps with sound.  When your teenager starts a band, that extra insulation may soften the sounds emanating from your garage.  It could keep your relationships with your neighbors on good terms.

Comment: @B540Glenn, it's also good for the standard hammering, sawing, vacuuming, swearing, etc. that goes on in a DIYers garage, too.

Comment: If you ever have a fire in your garage, insulation can slow the spread of it. A tenant demonstrated that convincingly on one of our rentals.

Comment: It seems like opening the doors would quickly change the temp, but the walls and floor and "stuff" in the garage will hold the temperature.  The air is a part of it, but a bast of cold air from outside would quickly reach a warmer equilibrium with the stuff the garage is made of.  It's like how "letting the cold air out of the fridge" really isn't a big deal.

Comment: @B540Glenn That's a popular fallacy. Insulation has little to no effect on sound. Sealing air gaps has a good effect on sound transmission, which may happen as a result of insulation. After that though, what stops sound is *mass*. A plywood or drywall inner skin inside a wood or metal shed will block more sound than any amount of lightweight insulation. If it's brick or block, no amount of insulation will make any difference to sound transmission.

Comment: ...All I can think about is the poor kitty on winter nights if you don't. =(

Comment: @jpmc26 Southern California winter nights.  Kitty will be fine.

Answer (score 14):

### Oh, yes

It's a cornerstone of **passive** solar design.

We spent $2.4M on a large building we intend to never heat.  We insulated it to the nines.  Here's what that does.

**Extremes of temperature** are moderated by building's thermal mass*, which (with the insulation) helps it resist changes in temperature. This affects

**Condensation**, which is significantly reduced or eliminated.  This makes life much easier for the contents of the building.

If you don't have enough thermal mass*, you can add some by installing large barrels of water or antifreeze.

---

* ”thermal mass" is the terminology used in building design, but it's actually a misnomer. Mass/weight does not store heat.  Atoms do.  And atoms vary in mass dramatically from 1 for hydrogen to 207 for lead.  But an atom's heat storage ability is [about the same](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity#Table_of_specific_heat_capacities), 20-30 j/mol/degK, most 24-26 j/mol/degK.  Different materials contain different mixes of atoms, so [their heat capacity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_mass#Materials_commonly_used_for_thermal_mass) *by mass* is all over the map.  Water is ideal.

Comment: How are the water "thermal mass" / heat sink's situated in the building? Are they in  a basement? Attic floor? Maintenance areas of each level? Are they sealed drums.. I find this interesting - more details would be appreciated.

Comment: "Mass/weight does not store heat. Atoms do." ...Atoms are mass... Maybe you mean chemical bonds do? Also, if you're gonna be technical, "heat" is a type of *energy transfer*, and is not a synonym of thermal energy (at least going by the formal thermodynamic terms).

Comment: @jpmc26: What Harper wrote was clear to me, even if the use of "atoms" was imprecise - the amount of heat you can store is not a function of the mass, but also has a factor of the specific heat of whatever compounds that mass consists of.

Comment: @jpmc26 you disagree because you disbelieve because my statement is bold.  Atoms possess mass as *one of their characteristics*. However mass is highly variable, from hydrogen (1u) to carbon (12u) to iron (58u) clear to uranium at 238u.  So 6 pounds of water and 207 pounds of lead have the same number of atoms.  When you look at the thermal storage capacity of substances, it correllates very poorly to its mass, and very well to the number of atoms in it. Check it out.  *It's not chemical bonds, that would only come into play if we burned it.*

Comment: @javadba it's not normally done, I am just saying in a storage type space, if you needed more thermal mass, that would be a way to do it.

Comment: @Harper It's technically the kinetic energy of the atoms, which I guess makes more sense on second reading. I wasn't really sure *what* you meant. As far as atoms "having mass as a characteristic," well, duh. Anything can be defined as the collection of its characteristics. My point is that you decided to be half pedantic, which just looks silly. If you're going to be pedantic, then don't stop half way.

Comment: It is not just atoms which store heat.  Hydgrogen has a specific heat of about 14 kJ/kg/K, helium has a specific heat of about 5.  Helium atoms are four times heavier than helium (so a kilo has four times fewer atoms), but helium only stores three times less heat.  It's a lot more complex than that.  Similarly, a polythene and iron.

Comment: @MartinBonner try the second column.  Hydrogen is 28.82 J/mol/K (2sqrt2??) and helium is 20.78 g/mol/K.  You're right, there's a 3/4 ratio, but they're both outliers.  Most elements are more toward the 24-26 range, like iron at 25.06 g/mol/k. Carbon seems to have a distortive effect, but even so, the rule of thumb of "25 g/mol/k per atom" seems to hold for molar quantities for many compounds, like water at 75 J/mol/K (3 atoms) and octane at 228 J/mol/K (26 atoms). Polyethylenes are hard to measure in molar quantities but their mass heat capacity is very similar to octane.

Comment: Comparing molar quantities of hydrogen and lead is near useless.  One's a gas and the other solid.  When you want to buffer temperature change in a large room, you'll quickly be concerned with the heat capacity on a mass or volume basis.  Unless you're buying cylinders and a fire suppression system, no one uses hydrogen for its thermal mass.  If molar heat capacity was important, the air in the room would be enough.  It's also the same reason you won't find the heat capacity of polyethylene on a molar basis.  Polyethylene does not have a distinct molar weight since chain length varies.

Comment: @ByronWall depends how much knowledge of chemistry you have.  My point is that "each atom stores about the same amount of heat" is a useful rule of thumb for those who do know something about the composition of materials. If you know taconite is mostly Fe and granite is coarsely SiO2. Then it's obvious granite will work much better than taconite since Si and O are much lighter than Fe.

Comment: Knowing about heat storage at the atomic or molecular level is useless for the layman.  It makes for a nice "rule of thumb" to tell people but isn't practical.  Everyday heat storage is concerned with the macro level where `energy/volume` or `energy/mass` is the important measure.  Molar units are useless outside of the Chemistry and Chemical Engineering realms.  Even in those fields molar units are not always used.

Comment: @ByronWall My answer only touches the edge of the subject with a whisk broom.  Remember something: **Bold statements require bold proofs**.  The crux of my claim, *"thermal mass" has nothing whatsoever to do with "actual mass", is a **very** bold statement!*  My first edit didn't support that *enough*, so I turned it up.

Answer (score 10):

A few things come into play. One is heat transfer from your home (or to it, in your case). If you keep your garage more comfortable, you improve the efficiency of the home's HVAC system. In my case, the uninsulated garage stays 20-30 degrees warmer than outside, mostly due to solar gain and heat loss from my home's conditioned space. This means my home loses less heat through the adjoining wall due to a lower temperature differential. Whether this will result in a net payoff is hard to say.

Another is comfort in the garage, as you mentioned. You can't "reset" the garage's interior temperature in a few minutes. Your slab acts as a massive heat sink, and all the garage's contents and wall structure also absorb heat. This means that, while air temps may change quickly with the door open, they'll return to roughly the same temp when you close the door. By keeping it cooler with insulation, which slows solar gain, it'll probably be cooler during the day as well.

Again, the finances are difficult to calculate because of the wildly varying factors involved. If you can do it cheaply, I would.

Comment: Insulation alone without heating or cooling will blunt the daily temperature fluctuations - it won't cool off quite as much at night or heat up quite as much during the day.   That's usually a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

We paid to insulate our garage in this house despite having absolutely zero plans to ever heat/cool it.  20 years of living here and I think we made the right choice.  The garage is south facing in a very hot climate, yet because of that insulation the temperature in there never gets nearly as extreme as it does outside.  Contrast that with my parents house with a south facing garage with a west wall of concrete block--that would easily get as hot as the outside and in the evening it was often hotter out there than outside.

On the other hand, our previous house with a north facing garage we didn't insulate.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that your attic is going to get a lot warmer than the surrounding air. In southern CA especially, the sun will bake your roof and, even with proper venting, you'll still have an ambient summer temperature in the 110+ range in your attic.

Without insulation in the attic, you're going to let that 110+ seep through the drywall and into the garage. In other words, you're potentially making your garage another near-attic. This will *increase* your heating and cooling costs because you're baking 2 sides of your climate controlled house instead of just one (and walls are typically too small to get much more than a R15, while most attics can easily take R60 or more). I would at least get an R30 over your garage.

Insulating your door is another option, but I find it overkill. Make sure you have good gaskets around your door first.